# CSS Grid margins too large and i Need them to scale

Tags: html, css

My code includes 4 boxes that should connect to the 4 corners of the page. I am using a CSS grid layout. But the margins on the right and bottom are too big, i don't see the code that is doing this. I have a CSS file that does all the work, and an index page that gets manipulated by the CSS file. How do I get this grid layout to scale?

blocks.css-->

```
 body {

    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 8ch auto;
     grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
     row-gap: 10px;       
}

/* blocks
#four
{
border-color: yellow;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
width: 25%;
text-align: center;
grid-column: 1 / 2;
grid-row: 2;
}
#three{
border-color: orange;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
width: 25%;
grid-column:  1/ 2;
grid-row: 1;    
}

#one{
border-color: blue;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
width: 25%;
grid-column: 2 / 2;
grid-row: 2;

}
#two {
 border-color: green;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 25%;
}
#link {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
text-align: center;
width: 25%;
}
```

index.htm-->-->index.htm -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocks</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="blocks.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">
Turns out you have a really fun time if you 
go to work every day and focus on being 
silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
</div>
<div id="two">
All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, 
and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
</div>
<div id="three">
Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters 
fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never 
mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
</div>
<div id="four">
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
</div>
<p id="link">
<a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
Brainy Quote
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide a codesandbox for quick debugging

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello! Please edit your question and add a screeenshot of what you are looking for.